# PSCustomObject foreach

Tags: powershell, foreach, custom-component

I've created a custom object and I'm having some trouble with the output of one array.

```
$i = "computername"
$adsi = [ADSI]"WinNT://$i"
$Object = $adsi.Children | ? {$_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user'} | % {
New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
    ComputerName = $i.toupper() -join ''
    UserName = $_.Name -join ''
    Groups = ($_.Groups()  |Foreach-Object {$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name",     'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)}) -join ',' 
    Disabled = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $i -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter "LocalAccount='$true'"|Select-Object -expandproperty Disabled 
    }  
  } 

$object
```

The problem is with the Disabled array, instead of showing one item per line I'm getting 
    `{False, True, False, False}` I know I have to probably add at `%` somewhere on that line but I'm not sure where.

Anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing makes sense to me - you're creating an array of objects holding `ComputerName`, `UserName`, etc. and in `Disabled` you're getting an array of values because you're querying  **all** local user accounts and getting their disabled status. I suspect what you want is to determine *each* user in turn is disabled. In which case, you need to extend the `Filter` on `Get-WMIObject` a bit to only get a single user.

```
$i = "computername"
$adsi = [ADSI]"WinNT://$i"
$Object = $adsi.Children | ? {$_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user'} | % {
$UserName = $_.Name -join '';
New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
    ComputerName = $i.toupper() -join ''
    UserName = $UserName
    Groups = ($_.Groups()  |Foreach-Object {$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name",     'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)}) -join ',' 
    Disabled = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $i -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter "LocalAccount='$true' and name='$UserName'"|Select-Object -expandproperty Disabled 
    }  
  } 

$object
```